# Problem Installing Xubuntu 12.04 Audio-Video codecs

Tags: 12.04, sound, xubuntu, xfce, codecs

I used Crouton to install Xubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with the XFCE environment on my HP Chromebook 11. I've gotten it all fully installed and everything; the only thing I'm doing now is the basic setup things, like adding codecs and other things like LibreOffice, VLC, Firefox, Ubuntu Software Center, etc. This information I got from 2 sources:

1. http://www.efytimes.com/e1/fullnews.asp?edid=137269
2. http://www.binarytides.com/better-xubuntu-14-04/ .

I'm currently on the same step at both URLs, which is #6 on Link 1 and #8 on Link 2.

Per the articles, which both said the same thing, I typed in

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-restricted-extras libavcodec-extra` and it didn't do

anything. It just kept on saying the same thing:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libavcodec-extra
```

I've spend the last hour or so scouring the internet for a solution, for a hint even at what is going on. I don't want to do a clean reinstall, for two reasons: 1) it's takes  like 1.5h just to get the croot fully installed, and 2) everything but this out of what I've done so far (up to #6 at Link 1 & up to #8 at Link 2) works except the audio. I've already installed flash, so YouTube works fine. It's just I can't hear any audio.

Please help?

Thanks in advance. I appreciate all the great help I've been getting from AskUbuntu lately. You all are great.

Comment: you have to enable the universe and multiverse repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to setting, and go to update & software, and then add multiverse and universe canonical, and then in then terminal enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-restricted-extra
```

and this might work fine this way.

Comment: Well, thanks. Unfortunately, despite my heavy desire not to, I had to uninstall Xubuntu from my Chromebook because the extra OS (at least I suspect it was that) was causing it to eat up more power than my charger could put in. Although I'm not sure, I highly suspect it was that because as soon as I uninstalled Xubuntu and reverted the system to its default OS functionality, it fixed that issue right up.

Thank you all, regardless! You have been wonderful!